# Using Twitter Bootstrap Header Dropdown

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have designed a whole website using Twitter Bootstrap and it works very well for the most part.  I have done quite a bit of CSS in the past but had never done a framework like this.

The main problem I have is that when the browser goes under 600px the and the header condenses into a dropdown (which I want) the dropdown goes behind images and some HTML elements such as text input boxes and other dropdown menus.

Is there any way to make this header dropdown menu opaque so that it is in front of every other element?  I would provide some code but I am not sure specifically what part of the Twitter Bootstrap stylesheet would be helpful.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">

              <div class="navbar-inner">

                  <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">

                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>

                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>

                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>

                  </a>

                  <a class="brand" href="/">Exployre</a>

                  <div class="nav-collapse">

                    <ul class="nav">

                      <li><a href="/map">Find</a></li>

                      <li><a href="/shareadventure">Share</a></li>

                      <li><a href="/home">Inspire</a></li>

                      <li><a href="/posts">Discuss</a></li>

                      <li><a href="/groups">Groups</a></li>

                      <li><a href="/profile">Profile</a></li>

                      <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>

                  <li>        

                        <form action="/search" class="navbar-search">

                          <div>

                            <input type="text" placeholder="Search" class="search-query pull-right" name="q" size="55" />

                          </div>

                        </form>

                        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/coop/cse/brand?form=cse-search-box&amp;lang=en"></script>

                      </li>



                    </ul>

                  </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->

              </div>

            </div>
```

I believe all of these classes are straight from the Twitter Bootstrap CSS without modification.

Comment: it's a z-index issue, impossible to help without code though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have a z-index on your website content that is a higher value than the z-index defined for the Dropdowns.

If you're using the LESS version of Twitter Bootstrap, open variables.less and find the line containing `@zindexDropdown` (on [line 144](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/less/variables.less#L144)). The default setting is 1000, you can change it to a number that is higher than the z-index on your content.

If you're using the normal CSS, it is defined in the rule for `.dropdown-menu` (on [line 2773](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/docs/assets/css/bootstrap.css#L2773)).

Comment: hmm do you think I need to change any of the other classes?  I changed that to 0 and it didn't have any visible effect.

Comment: When you say "I changed that to 0" did you mean that you changed the value of the z-index for the dropdowns to zero?  If so, you went the wrong direction, you need to make sure that the z-index is higher than whatever the z-index is for your website content (the stuff that is showing above your dropdowns).

Comment: I made it higher than everything else and it did not change anything.  then I made another div around that and made that higher just in case I was missing something and again that didn't have any effect.  When I scroll over the <li>'s they are in front of everything and so is all the text but the navbar background is not in the forefront

Comment: Well at this point you need to make your code available. Can't help you blind.

Comment: sorry for the delay I didn't have my dev machine the last two days.  I just added the code